# Selectize.js: How to sort options on values which are integers?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of options which i feed into selectize as follows:

```
<select data-placeholder="Select #" id="my-select"></select>
var myOptions = [1, 20, 7, 30, 90, 365].map( function ( value) {
    return {
        text: value,
        value: value
    };
});  
$('#my-select').selectize({
    options: myOptions,
    create: true,
    sortField: {
        field: 'text',
        direction: 'asc'
    }
});
```

When I load the view the select box appears with options sorted correctly the first time but when i add a custom option, 100 in my case, the list does not update itself correctly in sorted order. It looks like the list did get resorted but it assumed the field 'text' was of type string and not integers. Is there a way, in selectize, to specify sorting on an integer based field ?

Here is how the order of options looks when selectbox is initialized and after i have added a custom input, 100, to it.

INITIAL ------- AFTER CUSTOM INPUT
1 ------------------ 1
7 ------------------ 100
30 ----------------- 7
90 ----------------- 30
200 ---------------- 90
365 ---------------- 200
---------------------- 365

Comment: you are sorting strings, not numbers. maybe you need a callback for numbers.

Comment: how do i edit my question post above? i am new (in terms of posting questions) to SO.

Comment: with [edit] below your post, or by clicking the link.

Comment: many thanks for replying so promptly @nina, and pointing out the edit link below the post, it is so subtle i was missing it in plain sight. thanks a lot. i couldn't find any simple way to do it through their api, https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md . I am hoping someone with more experience with the library might have an easy solution.

Comment: where is the part where the number gets inserted? if you could insert a number, then it could sort correctly, i suppose.

Comment: @nina custom inputs are being handled by the library, although i did try to handle those too with onOptionAdd: function (value, data) {
            this.addOption({
                text: parseInt(value),
                value: parseInt(value)
            });
            this.refreshOptions( myOptions);
        } but did NOT work for me.

Comment: apologies for forgetting to share the solution to the problem back then, however i posted it just now, in case someone else comes looking for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var userAddedOption = parseInt($('#user_added_option').val(), 10); // assume its = 100
var myOptions =  [1, 7, 30, 90, 365];
myOptions.push(userAddedOption);
myOptions = myOptions.map(function(value) {
    return {
        text: value,
        value: value
    };
});
$('#my-select').selectize({
    options: myOptions,
    create: true,
    sortField: function(item1, item2) {
        return item1.value - item2.value;
    },
    onInitialize: function() {
        this.addItem(userAddedOption);
    }
});
```

Comment: another way is to update options after they are added to hold numerical values rather than textual as follows:
$('#my-select').selectize({
        options: myOptions,
        create: true,
        sortField: [{
  field: 'text', 
  direction: 'asc'
 }],
        onOptionAdd: function(value, data) {
  this.updateOption(value, {
   text: parseInt(data.text, 10),
   value: parseInt(data.text, 10)
  });
        }
    });

Comment: Is this some undocumented feature? I don't see it in the documentation: https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/v0.14.0/docs/usage.md (e.g. sortField accepting a function)